Need to make a partition method for a quicksort class
I need to build a partition method for a quicksort file, my current code just gets stuck somewhere and loops forever.
private static int partition(int[ ] data, int first, int n)
   // Precondition: n > 1, and data has at least n elements starting at
   // data[first].
   // Postcondition: The method has selected some "pivot value" that occurs
   // in data[first]. . .data[first+n-1]. The elements of data have then been
   // rearranged and the method returns a pivot index so that
   //   -- data[pivot index] is equal to the pivot;
   //   -- each element before data[pivot index] is <= the pivot;
   //   -- each element after data[pivot index] is > the pivot.
   {
       
       int tooBigIndex = first + 1;
       int pivot = data[first];
       int tooSmallIndex = n - 1;
              
       while(tooBigIndex <= tooSmallIndex) {
           while (tooBigIndex < data.length - 1 && data[tooBigIndex] <= pivot) {
               tooBigIndex--;
           }
           while (data[tooSmallIndex] > pivot) {
               tooSmallIndex++;
           }
           if   (tooBigIndex < tooSmallIndex) {
               int temp = data[tooSmallIndex];
               data[tooSmallIndex] = data[tooBigIndex];
               data[tooBigIndex + 1] = temp;
           }
       }
       
       
       
       data[tooSmallIndex] = pivot;
       
       return tooSmallIndex;
       
   }

This is my current code, it's supposed to do every number in the array except for the first and last but all it does is throw array index out of bounds exceptions or just get stuck somewhere in a loop

I'm pretty sure this is wrong: while (tooBigIndex < data.length - 1 You don't want tooBigIndex to grow past tooSmallIndex.  This is probably not the only error, just the first I noticed.

Actually this seems really wrong: int tooSmallIndex = n - 1;  Should that be int tooSmallIndex = first + n - 1;?  I think you should explain the code a little better (to us, in the question), there seems to be something off here.
